# How to copy string from web page and write to a file in python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I don't really know python and I researched a lot but this is the best code that I could come up with

```
import urllib2
import re

file = open('C:\Users\Sadiq\Desktop\IdList.txt', 'w')

for a in range(1,11):
    s = str(a)
    url='http://fanpagelist.com/category/top_users/view/list/sort/fans/page%s' + s
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    for x in range(1,21):
        id = re.search('php?id=(.+?)"',page)
        file.write(id)
file.close()
```

I am trying to copy the id number. In the web page its something like this

> href="/like_box.php?id=6679099553"

I just want the number written to a txt file on a new line. There are ten webpages that i want to scrape and I want only the first 20 ids from each page.
But when i run my code, it shows 403 error 
How to do it?

This is the full error

```
C:\Users\Sadiq\Desktop>extractId.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Sadiq\Desktop\extractId.py", line 7, in <module>
page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 437, in open
response = meth(req, response)
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 475, in error
return self._call_chain(*args)
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: print url and you see that it is incorrect. If you use `+` then you don't need `%s`. To connect two strings you need `"A" + "B"` or `"A%s" % "B"`

Comment: btw: `write()` doesn't add `"\n"` so you need `write(id + "\n")`

Comment: thanks but that still didn't help. i am still getting the same error

Comment: print url and use it in browser to check if it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for html scraping:

```
from requests import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


with open('C:\Users\Sadiq\Desktop\IdList.txt', 'w') as out:
    for page in range(1,11):
        url='http://fanpagelist.com/category/top_users/view/list/sort/fans/page%d' % page # no need to convert 'page' to string
        html = request('GET', url).text # requests module easier to use
        soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
        for a in soup.findAll('a', {'class':"like_box"})[:20]: # search all links ('a') that have property "like_box"
            out.write(a['href'].split('=')[1] + '\n')
```

Comment: I am getting this error

C:\Users\Sadiq\Desktop>extractId.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sadiq\Desktop\Batman Quiz\extractId.py", line 9, in <module>
    soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\bs4\__init__.py", line 165, in __init__
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requeste
d: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?

Comment: Try to remove 'lxml': `soup = bs(html)`

Comment: It didn't work. It told me (it printed a message as if it was a person, weird!) that i should write html.parser beside html.
But this code is writing all of the ids on that page.
I only want the first 20. Could you change your answer to this effect?
 Also please correct Soap to Soup. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok. You are probably using python2.7. Updated answer